# I want to fetch value if the user has clicked on authentication link or not

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Using firebase I am providing two signup options, one is with google and another one is with Email.
while using email, when a user is submitting the email, firebase is sending authentication email, and we are directing our user to the next page to set up a password. While the user is on the password setup page, I want to add a checker where we will check if the user has been authenticated or not by clicking the link, if not I want to display an error message.
I am doing this on react based webapp

isemailverified, useeffect is already given a fair shot but not giving the respond they are sending the default state.
I was expecting to receive the change in the state but thats not happening.

Comment: There are dozens of things that could be going wrong here, so it's hard to say what the case is. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.